# How do I populate trees with many random integers?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, populate

I'm writing a program that's supposed to populate ten random trees with 1000 random values, ranging from 0 to 300. This is the code of my tester class. When I run this program, however, it prints out the exact same thing for each tree, while code-wise it looks like I'm adding different random numbers.

I have a feeling that it keeps adding the same number, but I do not know how to change it. I am not very familiar with the Random class or Math.random().

```
package ch08.trees;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BSTTest {
ArrayList<BinarySearchTree<Integer>> trees = new ArrayList<BinarySearchTree<Integer>>();


public BSTTest() {
    for(int h = 0; h < 10; h++) { //Populate the arraylist with 10 trees
        trees.add(new BinarySearchTree<Integer>());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Run through 10 trees in array
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) { //1000 integers for each tree
            trees.get(i).add((int) Math.random()*300);
        }
}

public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int height = trees.get(i).height();
        int optimal = trees.get(i).optimal();
        double ratio = (double) height/(double) optimal; //Ratio only useful when decimal
        s += "Tree " + i + "--" + "Height: " + height + ", Optimal Height: " + optimal + 
                ", Bushyness Ratio: " + ratio + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BSTTest a = new BSTTest();
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Math.random is returning a double value between 0.0 and 1.0 so casting in to an int is wrong.

it is like doing `0 * 300` or `1 * 300` == not very random.

if you were to multiply by 300.00, the result would be quite different.

Also consider http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Keep a `Random` instance in memory and call `nextInt` #nextInt()